# Using ROCR package difficulties

Tags: r, glm

I'm following an analysis of German Credit data and I got an error which I'm failing to rectify because I already installed the **ROCR** package. Below is the code that uses the **ROCR**:

```
#load library
library(ROCR)

#score test data set
test$score <- predict(m,type='response',test)
pred <- prediction(test$score,test$good_bad)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf)
```

Now, after running `pred`, I get the following error:

```
>pred <- prediction(test$score,test$Good_Bad)
Error: could not find function "prediction".
```

This also happens when I try to execute the following line:

```
>perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
Error: could not find function "performance"
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should be getting those errors. Did the package load successfully?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue... If you look closely, it says:

```
Loading required package: gplots
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘KernSmooth’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘ROCR’ was built under R version 3.0.3 
2: package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.0.3 
Error: package ‘gplots’ could not be loaded
```

I simply installed the install.packages("gplots") and then loaded the library and it loaded and found the function without any issues.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue, and despite already having "gplots" installed and apparently up to date, I just re-installed it via command install.packages("gplots") and it seemed to work ok.